# Why pathname expansion works like this?

Tags: bash

I have a directory structure like this:

```
.
├── dir
│   └── src
│       └── file.c
├── dir_a1
│   └── src
│       └── file.c
└── dir_a2
    └── src
        └── file.c
```

When I run the following command, the results are as expected:

```
echo dir{,_a[12]}/**/*.c 
#
dir/src/file.c
dir_a1/src/file.c
dir_a2/src/file.c
```

If I remove **file.c** from **dir_a2**, the results are still OK:

```
rm dir_a2/src/file.c
echo dir{,_a[12]}/**/*.c
#
dir/src/file.c
dir_a1/src/file.c
```

But when I remove **file.c** from **dir**, the results for that directory get messed up:

```
rm dir/src/file.c
echo dir{,_a[12]}/**/*.c
#
dir/**/*.c
dir_a1/src/file.c
```

Why bash decided to remove result of expansion for **dir_a2** but not for **dir**?

**globstar** is enabled in shell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brace expansion (that is, `{this,that,etc}`) is *not* a file glob, meaning that it expands to all values whether or not there's a file by that name. Thus, `dir{,_a[12]}/**/*.c` expands to the two glob patterns `dir/**/*.c` and `dir_a[12]/**/*.c`. The second expands to the only matching file, `dir_a1/src/file.c`, but the first doesn't match anything and is therefore left alone (and so it gets echoed literally).

If you don't want unmatched globs to be passed through, set the `nullglob` shell option, via `shopt -s nullglob`. But be aware that this will cause other things to act in weird ways, such as `ls /etc/*.nosuchextension` listing the current directory's contents. Another way to handle unmatched globs is the `failglob` shell option.

Comment: So if I remove the file from **dir_a1**, it will behave in the same way as for **dir**. Thanks, I couldn't figure that out :)

Comment: @xba: Exactly. echo would print "dir/**/*.c" and "dir_a[12]/**/*.c".